# Update dom after component rendered the view, best practice in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm seeking some advice how I should handle elements when working with Angular2. 
I have stored some elements id's in the localstorage, and want to set a selected class name on some specific elements.

For now I'm using this way:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {

// Check if seats has been selected before
var selectedSeats: elementInterface = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SelectedSeats'));

if (selectedSeats != null) {
  var outboundElement = document.getElementById(selectedSeats.outboundSelectedElement);
  var returnElement = document.getElementById(selectedSeats.returnSelectedElement);

  this.autoSelectSeats(outboundElement);
  this.autoSelectSeats(returnElement);
}

}
```

**Method:**

```
private autoSelectSeats(element: Element) {
    // Set selected class on element
    element.classList.add('selected');
}
```

I see two issues here. The first is the ngAfterViewChecked hook that fires more than once after the view is created. Is there something I can do so it only fires once?

Second: Is there a better way to get the element when you know the id and set a class attribute on it after the content has loaded?

I can't seem to find the Angular2 way of doing it, besides using this hook.

Any idea? Also, please don't post Jquery posts, as I don't want to implement that when using Angular :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a custom directive to each of your "seat" elements and let that directive add the CSS class?

In your **template**, the directive would be used as follows (I'm guessing, since you didn't show your template):

```html
<div *ngFor="let seat of seats" [highlight]="seat.id">
  ...
</div>
```

You need to pass some information to the directive to identify which seat it is working on. It seems better to pass an id directly (e.g. `seat.id`) rather than to rely on HTML ids (although in your case they might be one and the same).

Now the code for the **directive**:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  @Input() highlight: string;  // This will contain a seat.id

  constructor(el: ElementRef, ss: SeatService) {
    const selectedSeats = ss.getSelectedSeats();
    // If current seat found in selectedSeats, mark it as selected.
    if (selectedSeats.indexOf(this.highlight) !== -1) {
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('selected');
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I'm using an external service `SeatService` to get the data from localStorage is that Angular will create an instance of `HighlightDirective` for every match it finds in your template. You don't want to refetch the selected seats in every instance (the service lets you cache the seats and return the same data).

Comment: But how about if the user refresh the page? Then a new instanse will be created right?

Comment: I try implement something like this. Will report back when my directive is working.

Comment: What do you mean "refresh the page"? If you mean a hard refresh (browser refresh button), then the ENTIRE app will have to reboot. In that case, it doesn't really matter which implementation you picked.

Comment: Ye, i get it, we still using localstorage :) got the directive and retreive of selectedSeat from localstorage if it exist. Now i just need some logic on place.

Comment: Managed to get it to work with your great idea, Thanks for your help

Comment: Good news! Happy to help, @Mikkel. :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular way has pretty good documentation, classes are toggled using the following syntax: `[class.selected]="selected"`

Comment: Ye, but I got 50 elements that an NgFor has produced and want to highlight those elements that has been clicked on, when you visit the component again.

So have to find the element again. Thats why I stored the id's in localstorage.

Comment: you should add `selected` property to your model

Comment: So I should make a property on my model, and set it to true if it's selected?